# How to turn URL into downloadable GeoJSON file

Tags: javascript, import, export, geojson, arcgis

I'm trying to take a URL like this one:

https://a.mapillary.com/v3/images?client_id=Q2ZpVVBEYXFreDFRalB6Z0J5dWRtVzphNjlkMDVjZWMzMWIxMzNj&closeto=-87.59220807169899,41.769205512917&radius=1000

and turn the resulting GeoJSON file into something that can be imported into ArcGIS Online, or something similar.

I'm stuck, and would appreciate any help. Thanks. I am very new to all of this, and have been trying to accomplish this using JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating an anchor tag (`<a>`) with a  `download` attribute.
[The documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) define the behavior of the attribute as such.

> Prompts the user to save the linked URL instead of navigating to it. Can be used with or without a value:

```html
<a download href="https://a.mapillary.com/v3/images?client_id=Q2ZpVVBEYXFreDFRalB6Z0J5dWRtVzphNjlkMDVjZWMzMWIxMzNj&closeto=-87.59220807169899,41.769205512917&radius=1000" >Download</a>
```

The `download` attribute can be empty or hold a value. This value can be the name of the file that the user will download, for example your situation: `download="locations.json"`.